# IE8 ignoring top-margin on floated div

Tags: internet-explorer, padding, margin

All browsers except IE8 are properly reading the css for the nav-menu margin on my site.  IE8 is ignoring any margin or padding I place on the nav css between the two full width divs (the logo div and menu div). The original files were from a simple responsive template I have edited.

I need the nav-menu div to be placed far enough down so not to interfere with background image.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're married to this structure and css approach:

```
<div id="header-inner" class="sixteen columns over">
  <div id="masthead" class="sixteen columns alpha"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <nav class="sixteen columns omega" id="main-nav" name="main-nav"></nav>
</div>
```

and floating both `#masthead` and `#main-nav` and positioning `#main-nav` absolutely at the bottom, then you need to assign  `#header-inner` an explicit height.  Other browsers are computing its height at 225px so that's where i'd start.

```
#header-inner{
height: 225px; 
}
```

Comment: Setting the height worked perfectly!  Such a simple fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For IE Purpose Only maybe you can ADD a Fix "Table or Div" Tag where you will Set it's Height at runtime (think jquery) when IE is detected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply JudgeProphet. I have tried resizing both divs in css so I could produce at least a fix for IE8, and the two divs will not react to one another.

Comment: Positioning might need to be fixed